# Is a falling object equation of motion a non-linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I'm attempting to model a falling object in state space form. Problem below.

[image]

I've modeled higher order differential equations as state space systems before but this problem is confusing me. The equation that's provided is clearly a differential equation, however, it includes a the independent variable itself (time) along with an initial condition.

I also think it's odd that I am being asked to model a second order system with three state variables (I believe two would suffice).

So my question, is a falling object equation of motion non-linear?

Answer (score 2):

> The equation that's provided is clearly a differential equation, however, it includes a the independent variable itself (time) along with an initial condition.

No, the equation that's provided is *a solution to* a differential equation. The differential equation is not provided.

> I also think it's odd that I am being asked to model a second order system with three state variables (I believe two would suffice).

You're right, but it's still possible to do what the problem requests.

> So my question, is a falling object equation of motion non-linear?

The differential equation you seek is linear.

Edit:

By the way, the problem is written incorrectly, which I only just noticed, because I expected to see the correct version! The equation given is $p=p_0+\dot pt +\frac12\ddot pt^2$, but it should be $p=p_0+v_0t +\frac12at^2$ where $v_0$ is the initial velocity and $a$ is the constant acceleration due to gravity. The equation given is actually *wrong* if evaluated at any time other than $t=0$, where it is trivially correct. It also happens that at $t=0$, we have $\dot p = v_0$, and it is always true that $\ddot p = a$, which is why the author(s) made the mistake of conflating these expressions.

Comment: Given that the equation relates the function, first, and second derivative would make me assume it's a differential equation correct? If it was a solution to a differential equation it would simply be a function of time correct?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. Will explain in an edit.